# Calculate exponential moving average with values in different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data structure like

```
data = {
    "Home Team": ["A", "C", "D", "B", "A"],
    "Away Team": ["B", "A", "A", "A", "D"],
    "Home Feat": [1, 2, 0, 10, 7],
    "Away Feat": [2, 3, 0, 5, 1],
    "Primary Key": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I am trying to compute the exponential moving average per team in new features `Home Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games` and `Away Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games`. I have this super slow and long function, which takes aprox 4 min for 8000 rows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> def extract_feature_per_team(df, feature, team, against):
...     """
...     Extracts feature for per team from columns, that comes in pairs of two.
...     """
...     result = df.copy(deep=True)
...     result.columns = result.columns.str.split(expand=True)
...     if not against:
...         result = result.stack(0).loc[lambda x: x["Team"] == team, feature].tolist()
...     else:
...         result = result.stack(0).loc[lambda x: x["Team"] != team, feature].tolist()
...     return pd.DataFrame(data={team: result})
... 
>>> def add_Exp_Mov_Avg_FEAT_Last_OFFSET_Games(df, feature, offset):
...     """
...     Adds features "Home Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games" and "Away
...     Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games" based on "Season", "Home Team",
...     "Away Team", "Home {feature}" and "Away {feature}" for a given dataframe
...     and offset. Values of new features are float (rounded to 2 decimals). This
...     function prevents overlaps between saisons. IMPORTANT: Reindex df before
...     usage!
...     """
...     col_home = f"Home Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games"
...     col_away = f"Away Exp Mov Avg {feature} Last {offset} Games"
...     df[col_home] = -1.0
...     df[col_away] = -1.0
...     for index, row in df.iterrows():
...         season = row["Season"]
...         # home
...         tmp = df.iloc[: index + 1]
...         team = row["Home Team"]
...         tmp = tmp.loc[
...             ((tmp["Home Team"] == team) | (tmp["Away Team"] == team))
...             & (tmp["Season"] == season)
...         ]
...         tmp = tmp[["Home Team", "Away Team", f"Home {feature}", f"Away {feature}"]]
...         result = (
...             extract_feature_per_team(tmp, feature, team, False)
...             .ewm(span=offset)
...             .mean()
...             .shift(1)
...             .round(2)[team]
...             .iloc[-1]
...         )
...         if np.isnan(result):
...             result = 0.0
...         df.at[index, col_home] = result
...         # away
...         tmp = df.iloc[: index + 1]
...         team = row["Away Team"]
...         tmp = tmp.loc[
...             ((tmp["Home Team"] == team) | (tmp["Away Team"] == team))
...             & (tmp["Season"] == season)
...         ]
...         tmp = tmp[["Home Team", "Away Team", f"Home {feature}", f"Away {feature}"]]
...         result = (
...             extract_feature_per_team(tmp, feature, team, False)
...             .ewm(span=offset)
...             .mean()
...             .shift(1)
...             .round(2)[team]
...             .iloc[-1]
...         )
...         if np.isnan(result):
...             result = 0.0
...         df.at[index, col_away] = result
...     return df
... 
>>> data = {
...     "Season": ["2021-2022", "2021-2022", "2021-2022", "2021-2022", "2021-2022"],
...     "Home Team": ["A", "C", "D", "B", "A"],
...     "Away Team": ["B", "A", "A", "A", "D"],
...     "Home Feat": [1, 2, 0, 10, 7],
...     "Away Feat": [2, 3, 0, 5, 1],
... }
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
>>> add_Exp_Mov_Avg_FEAT_Last_OFFSET_Games(df, "Feat", 3)
test = {"Season": [1, 3, 0, 5, 7]}
pd.DataFrame(data=test).ewm(span=3).mean().shift(1)
      Season Home Team Away Team  ...  Away Feat  Home Exp Mov Avg Feat Last 3 Games  Away Exp Mov Avg Feat Last 3 Games
0  2021-2022         A         B  ...          2                                0.00                                0.00
1  2021-2022         C         A  ...          3                                0.00                                1.00
2  2021-2022         D         A  ...          0                                0.00                                2.33
3  2021-2022         B         A  ...          5                                2.00                                1.00
4  2021-2022         A         D  ...          1                                3.13                                0.00

[5 rows x 7 columns]
>>> # doublecheck
>>> 
>>> test = {"Test": [1, 3, 0, 5, 7]}
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=test).ewm(span=3).mean().shift(1)
     Season
0       NaN
1  1.000000
2  2.333333
3  1.000000
4  3.133333
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to solve/rewrite this?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Did you try [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)?

Comment: I did not try ewm. That's the question, because my data is in different columns. Anyway, my code is full of sh... I am trying to update my question asap.

Comment: I guess I pinned down my problem a little more clearly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869665/extract-values-from-different-columns-in-python

Comment: I updated my question, now the function is a least working correct.